# complex column design in Cassandra and query with Hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have a requirement to design like following

```
Row      Column          Column     
 A  |      B        |      E      |

       SubColumn         SubColumn
       C        D       F        G
       1        2       3        4
```

I don't know if this type of structure is possible. also i would like to know How to query such a table using Hector client. It would be nice if I can read some examples of insertion , deletion and updation using Hector.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, Read on Cassndra's `ColumnFamily`, `SuperColumn`, `Column`, etc. A good starting point to understanding Cassandra is to read [WTF is a SuperColumn](http://arin.me/post/40054651676/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model) by Arin Sarkissian.

Comment: Do u have any examples of HEctor to do query opertions on such a architecture...

Comment: Do you have to use Hector? There is Apache Thrift to use.

Comment: Yes i have started already with Hector... can't change now otherwise I have to change a lot of places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a Column on a SuperColumn with Mutator is quite similar to what we have already seen. The only difference is we are now creating an HSuperColumn in place of HColumn to provide some additional structure. For example, if we wanted to store our users under the "billing" department, we would use the following call to Mutator:

```
 Mutator<String> mutator =
 HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, stringSerializer);
 mutator.insert("billing", "Super1", HFactory.createSuperColumn("jsmith",
 Arrays.asList(HFactory.createStringColumn("first", "John")),
 stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer));
```

As for retrieval of a SuperColumn, the simple case is almost identical to retrieval of a standard Column. The only difference is the Query implementation used.

```
 SuperColumnQuery<String, String, String, String> superColumnQuery =
 HFactory.createSuperColumnQuery(keyspace, stringSerializer,
 stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
 superColumnQuery.setColumnFamily("Super1")
 .setKey("billing").setSuperName("jsmith");
  Result<HSuperColumn<String, String, String>> result = superColumnQuery.execute();
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your own question, if I may ask?